# Is it possible to disable context switching of a specific thread?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, operating-system, pthreads

I am working on a multithreading c/c++ program in Linux system. Currently, one design may require me to create multiple pthreads (say 100), and each process one task. However, I hope the CPU core could complete one pthread of task before switching to another one. For example, if I can allocate 8 CPU cores for my program and I create 16 pthreads, I want them to work on the first 8 pthreads until hit `cv_wait()` or return point and switch to another pthread. Is there any **efficient** way to disable context switching of one specific CPU thread until the current pthread call `cv_wait()`?
Create a `cv` for each task and put them into a queue might work, but that could give too much overhead.

Comment: You cannot control with a fine grain the scheduling of the thread in user-land. You can control the affinity of threads though. Generally any relation with the OS scheduler tends to be slow because of system calls. Why don't you create a thread pool with your own application-level scheduling. Besides, you can re-use condition variables if needed. There is no reason to have more condition variables than the number of thread AFAIK.

Comment: For Linux and only Linux; if you have 8 CPUs, you could consider having 8 threads using `SCHED_OTHER` and 8 threads using `SCHED_IDLE`. In that case the scheduler will give CPU time to the `SCHED_OTHER` threads whenever possible (and only give CPU time to the `SCHED_IDLE` threads if `SCHED_OTHER` thread/s are blocked/waiting) .

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you may want the `SCHED_FIFO` realtime scheduling class.  Threads in this class are not pre-empted by other threads at the same thread priority - they only move to the bottom of the run queue (for that static thread priority) when they voluntarily yield or become blocked (including blocking on a mutex, condition variable, IO, etc).

However, a better design is likely to have a smaller number of threads (one or two per CPU core), with each processing multiple units of work in sequence, rather than one thread per unit of work.  This amortises the thread startup cost across more work items and is generally more efficient.  You can then use ordinary scheduling classes and don't need to worry about context switching, since your threads are written to fully process one work item before moving to the next.

Comment: Re, "...bottom of the run queue..." You might point out that there is, _in effect,_ one run queue per priority level. When there's contention for CPU time, A SCHED_FIFO thread with a higher priority always will run before a lower-priority thread even if the lower priority thread has been waiting longer. You might also point out that "sleep" does not only mean `sleep()` and its like. A thread also "voluntarily sleeps" when it waits for a mutex or a condition variable, waits for any IPC object, waits in a blocking I/O call, etc.

Comment: That's true, normally we should consider having each thread runs repeatedly on multi workloads. But for some specific reasons, that requires quite a lot of work to change the original code structure. Therefore, I am just looking for possible easier solutions. Thanks so much for your answer!

Comment: Sadly, in Linux most of this is restricted (`CAP_SYS_NICE` before version 2.6.12 of the kernel,  an overcomplicated mess involving `RLIMIT_RTPRIO` for later versions) which makes it almost unusable for normal apps intended to be installed easily by other people (in addition to turning the program into a security risk).